# Maven cargo during merging web.xml not include all error-page

Tags: java, maven, maven-cargo

I trying to merge two war files using maven cargo plugin. The problem is that. I have only one web.xml in one archive. Other archives not include web.xml. So the situation looks like below:

- first.war --> with web.xml
- second.war --> without web.xml
- third.war --> without web.xml

So after merging my merged file **uberwar.war** file should contain exactly the same web.xml which is included in first.war.

Every tags in merged web.xml are the same **instead of error-page**. There is only taken first error-page from web.xml. Rest of the error-page tags are skipped. I dont know why. Have someone exeprience with this plugin and could help with issue?? I will be grateful for any help.

**1. assemble.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<uberwar>
    <wars>
       <war>org.vcm.modules:core-web</war>
       <war>org.vcm.modules:attributes-web</war>
       <war>org.vcm.modules:delivers-web</war>
       <war>org.vcm.modules:movies-web</war>
       <war>org.vcm.modules:zones-web</war>
       <war>org.vcm.modules:opinions-web</war>
       <war>org.vcm.modules:payments-web</war>
       <war>org.vcm.modules:storages-web</war>
       <war>org.vcm.modules:taxes-web</war>
       <war>org.vcm.shops:shops-web</war>
   </wars>
```

**2. pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
   <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.9</version>
   <extensions>true</extensions>
   <configuration>
       <descriptor>src/assemble/merge.xml</descriptor>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found cause. The problem was with my web.xml version. I used 3.1 when I change to 2.3 the merging process working correct. It seems the cargo plugin analyze the xml in different way when is newest version.